# Quotation symbol changes i to ï with Dutch language

Tags: babel, dutch

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
 het "interessante" voorbeeld
\end{document}
```

this results in ïnteressante"voorbeeld.

I can partially overcome it by adding a space \ but then i get a real extra unwanted space
" interessante"voorbeeld.
Note the space after the second " is also gone...

How can this be solved?

Comment: You don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 4):

Every manual on LaTeX will tell you that the proper method for inputting quotes is ***not*** using `"`.

You should do either

```
het ``interessante'' voorbeeld
```

or

```
het “interessante” voorbeeld
```

With `babel-dutch`, the combination `"`<vowel> prints the vowel with the diaeresis above:

```
"a "e" "i "o "u
```

will print

> ä ë ï ö ü

And `"` followed by a space ignores it (for technical reasons). The straight double quote character `"` has also other usages, see the `babel` manual.

Example, note I'm loading `fontenc` with the T1 option, which is recommended for Dutch.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}

het "interessante" voorbeeld (wrong)

het ``interessante'' voorbeld (right)

het “interessante” voorbeld (right)

"a "e "i "o "u

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These seem to be language-specific settings loaded by package `babel`. Note that even if this particular behaviour is stopped, it will produce incorrect pair of quotation marks as seen here:

[image: 1]

This is surely not what you want.

The correct way to do this is by using the backtick symbol (` for single quotes, `` for double quotes) on the left and on the right, using the single quote '.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}
het ``interessante'' voorbeeld
\end{document}
```

[image: 3]

A safer way is to use the quotation package `csquotes`. It takes care of the language-specific typesetting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
het \enquote{interessante} voorbeeld
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

Comment: the lower en upper quotes are indeed default used in Dutch, but in theory this is more used for a spoken sentence and in most books, it's not used anymore because the lower quotes look ugly. I'd like to use upper quotes, per today i have the non-directional ones. in the csquotes package i don't see Dutch.

Comment: @MrI2C I am not very familiar with typographic conventions of Dutch, but if you need straight quotes, have a look at `\textquotesingle` from package `textcomp`.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of the answers above:
\newcommand{\dq}[1]{"#1"}
this seems to solve the issue and it's quite handy tbh...
I already used
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{"#1"}}
and this solved the issue as well...
Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: This helps: In a plain text editor that has search capability, find each instance of `"` in your document, and replace it with something else (there are exceptions). I do this, and also search for any numeral that is immediately followed by unescaped `%` (because I probably meant actual percent, no comment).